# Cannot create Maven project in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm trying to create a Maven project in Netbeans (for the first time), 
Every time i try to create a project, i get this error message:

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD FAILURE
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 0.095s Finished at: Thu Jul 03 12:07:01 CEST 2014 Final
>   Memory: 4M/112M
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid
>   lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or
>   :[:]:.
>   Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize,
>   generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources,
>   process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources,
>   process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources,
>   test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package,
>   pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,
>   install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean,
>   clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
>   The system cannot find the path specified.

and i the project folder/files aren't created.

I'm using the Netbeans 8 IDE and download the full one (that contain J2EE and stuff), does that mean i have Maven installed by default, or i have to download and install it separately?

Comment: Do you have internet connection? Maven need internet to access Central repository.

Comment: yes, i'm using it right now.

Comment: Can you please outline the exact steps you have taken, especially the project template chosen?

Comment: File -> New Project -> Maven -> Web Application, then "next next next ..."

Comment: Can you please provide more of the console log - there must have been some error before the failure.

Comment: here is the whole console output http://pastebin.com/1wp6bqah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if there is settings.xml file present on your system at below path
C:\Users\your_username\.m2\

There will a folder repository and settings.xml file inside .m2 folder

If the settings.xml file is not present, create it yourself.

Sample Content of settings.xml below.
Enter the proxy IP address and port which you are using in  and  tags respectively.

```
<settings>
<proxies>
<proxy>
   <id>default</id>
   <active>true</active>
   <protocol>http</protocol>
   <host><IP Address></host>
   <port>8080</port>
 </proxy>
</proxies>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven should be bundled with NetBeans. You can also [download your own](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) (the one that comes with NetBeans is probably not the latest build) and tell NetBeans to use this concrete Maven. This is done in Tools -> Options -> Java -> Maven

After making sure Maven is correctly set (it should be by default), please right click on your project and go to -> Properties -> Actions. Here you should have different maven tasks, like Clean, Build, Test and more. You can also add your own.

If there are no Maven goals for you (highly unlikely), feel free to add your own. E.g. "clean install".

Maven should **work out of the box** in NetBeans just by right cliking your project and selecting Run, Clean, Test etc.

Comment: The project is not even being created, so how can i access the Project Properties

Comment: You download it again?

Comment: ok, so i downloaded the new Maven, (Version 3.2.2), and same thing happens. when i create a new maven, i get that error, and no project is created.

Comment: One more thing comes to my mind: Windows administration rights. Don't you create your project under windows into some folder, where you need administration rights to write to ? Like C:/Users/YourName/... ? If so, try running NetBeans as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

this could be related to jdk 8, maven 3.2.2 and or space in path to netbeans/maven. Please try with the the maven shipping with netbeans first. if it still doesn't work, creating a simple Maven Java application should work (as in 8.0 it's not using maven archetypes to create the project).

In any case, please file an issue at https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/ with detailed description of your setup (the detailed output log should help)

Comment: or programing&lesson path in your workdir could also be a contributing factor

Comment: I tried using the shipped Marven first, and i've had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10 Pro and stack configuring the proxy setting in settings, try deactivating proxy in settings>Networks&Internet>proxy>Authomatic detect settings(off)

[image: below is an image with proxy(off)]